# Entity Framework won't detect foreign key from database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, edmx-designer

I've got two tables - `Appointment` and `User`. Appointments can be linked to two different Users - a student and a member of staff. The `Appointment` table contains two foreign keys: `StaffUsername` and `ExternalID`. These reference columns in the `User` table named `Username` (the `User` table's PK) and `ExternalID` (a UNIQUE index). Here are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Appointment]
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [AppointmentTypeID] INT NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] DATETIME NOT NULL,    
    [AppointmentSlotID] INT NULL,    
    [StaffUsername] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [ExternalID] NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
    [BookedBy] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [BookedTimestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [ReminderEmailSentTimestamp] DATETIME NULL,
    [CancelledBy] NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    [CancelledTimestamp] DATETIME NULL,
    [StudentDidNotAttend] BIT NULL,
    [LastModifiedTimestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedBy] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Appointment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Appointment_AppointmentType] FOREIGN KEY ([AppointmentTypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AppointmentType]([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Appointment_AppointmentSlot] FOREIGN KEY ([AppointmentSlotID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AppointmentSlot]([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Appointment_User_StaffUsername] FOREIGN KEY ([StaffUsername]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User]([Username]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Appointment_User_ExternalID] FOREIGN KEY ([ExternalID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User]([ExternalID])
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [Username] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    [IsStaff] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [ExternalID] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [LastLogin] DATETIME NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Username] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_ExternalID] UNIQUE ([ExternalID])
)
```

Unfortunately, when I use the *Update model from database* option in the EDMX model designer, it will not pick up the foreign key on the `ExternalID` columns. It remains looking like this (highlighted in green are the properties relating to the relationship which is modelled correctly, in yellow are the properties which should relate to a second relationship but are being ignored):
[image: Screenshot showing EDMX Designer with missing relationship between tables]

I know from experience that the EDMX designer can be quirky at times, especially when detecting changes to objects, so I've tried all the usual tricks. I've checked in `Web.config` that my connection string is pointing to the correct database. I've deleted the `Appointment` and `User` tables in the designer completely and run the *Update* command again. I've tried that with a save and restart of Visual Studio between deletion and update, too.

To check the relationship is correct in the database I've created a database diagram in SSMS which shows the troublesome relationship correctly:

[image: Screenshot showing the table relationship in an SSMS database diagram]

I've also created a brand new project and added a new Entity Data Model pointing to the same database with the same credentials, just in case the issue was related to the fact that I'm updating an existing model, but no dice. Even in the new project, the relationship isn't detected.

I also tried to create the Navigation Property manually, but as you can see from this screenshot, the foreign key I'd need to select isn't available in the dropdown list:

[image: Screenshot of Add Navigation Property window in Visual Studio]

I don't know if the issue somehow relates to the fact that the `ExternalID` column isn't the primary key of the `User` table, or maybe its `NVARCHAR(10)` data type. I've no idea, to be honest.

Any suggestions as to why this foreign key isn't being detected? And how I can fix it? My project targets .NET Framework 4.6 and I'm using EF6. Obviously I'm using Database First.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF6 an Entity only has one key, and so all Navigation Properties must use a Foreign Key that references the same key.  EF Core supports [Alternate Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys), and supports a Database-First workflow with [Reverse Engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I suspected it was something I was doing that EF wasn't designed to handle. I ended up refactoring so that the second relationship between the two tables wasn't required.